# Making Xinput commands permanent "For complete noobs"

Tags: raspbian, lxde, xinput

As the title suggests, I need to rotate the touch input on a DSI display.

I am successful in rotating the input with this entered into the terminal.

```
xinput set-prop 'seeed-tp' 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

I need this to happen on boot.

> I have read that adding them to ~/.xsessionrc and or ~/.xinputrc is
> the right thing to do

However I do not know where .xsessionrc OR .xinputrc are located, and even if I did, I do not know how to add a command to those files to make them work.

Please advise for the total noobs please.

> me

Comment: Which graphics environment? Gnome/KDE/Xfce4 ... Because you might be able to add that to your startup scripts from the graphical interface.

Comment: Luckily as a noob I do know how to do that...
.
sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager

* 0            /usr/bin/startlxde-pi      90        auto mode

Answer (score 2):

The answer is as follows:

navigate to :

/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d

In that folder there should be several config files. Reading these files gives you an idea what should be placed into your own custom config.

Make a custom config by opening the terminal in that folder.

```
sudo nano 99-configuration.conf
```

in that file you'll need this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "calibration"
    MatchProduct    "your product here"
    Option "TransformationMatrix" "1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1"
EndSection
```

You can get the "your product here" by typing:

```
xinput list
```

however in my situation, that configuration only applies when the terminal is opened. Very strange behavior.